# How to define custom property on typescript and use it with anonymous object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created my own custom getDate() method in my Angular component

```
getDate(date: Date){
    return date.format("dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm").toString();
}
```

I getting string JSON data from the database. This JSON is something like this

`

```
 "{"field":"date","oldValue":"Mon Mar 25 00:00:00 GMT 2019","newValue":"Tue Mar 26 00:00:00 GMT 2019"},  {"field":"techniqueType","oldValue":"Intra","newValue":"Intralesional"}
```

`

My getList method looks like

```
    getList(patientId?: number, pageNo?: number) {
       const auditTrailSubscription = 
         this._auditTrailService.getAuditTrailUrl(patientId, pageNo, 
         GridConfig.ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
          .subscribe(
            result => {
            try {
              this.results = [];
              this.totalItems = result.recordsCount;
              this.auditTrailList = result.lstRecords;
              this.auditTrailList.forEach(x => {
              let jschanges = JSON.parse(`[${x.jsonChanges}]`);
              jschanges.forEach(z => {
                this.results.push({
                  userName: x.userName,
                  timestamp: x.timestamp,
                  entityName: x.entityName,
                  field: z.field,
                  oldValue: z.oldValue instanceof Date ? 
                        this.getDate(z.oldValue) : z.oldValue,
                  newValue: z.newValue instanceof Date ? 
                     this.getDate(z.newValue) : z.newValue
                });
              });
            });
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        err => {
          this.handleError(err);
        }
      );

    this.addSubscription("auditTrail", auditTrailSubscription);
  }
```

Html file

```
    <tr *ngFor="let at of results | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 
         _ITEMS_PER_PAGE, currentPage: crtPage, totalItems: totalItems }"
        [attr.data-row-id]="at.userId">
        <td>{{ at.userName }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.timestamp ? (at.timestamp | date: 
        AUDIT_TRAIL_DATE_TIME_FORMAT  ) :  'Unknown' }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.entityName }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.field | titlecase  }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.oldValue }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.newValue }}</td>
      </tr>
```

So I need to use my custom getDate() method and check if oldValue and newValue is the type of Date then use getDate() custom method otherwise just return other value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.parse()`. Pass your date string into `Date.parse()` and if it returns a number then date string is a valid date. Something like this: -

```
if(isNaN(Date.parse("Tue Mar 26 00:00:00 GMT 2019"))){
     console.log("Invalid Date");
}
else {
    console.log("Valid Date")
}
```

**or**

```
var isDateValue =  (new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date") && !isNaN(new Date(date));
```

Let me know if it works for you or otherwise.

Comment: Please look at comment below which I wrote. It is some different situation in my case. I tried also Date.parse it does not work.

Comment: I don't want to check if Date is valid or not. I just want if is date then show my custom date format otherwise other properties, This values are dynamic which I grab from json using JSON.parse so it converts to string old values and new values. I just need conversion not validity.

Comment: Could you please create your scenario in stackblitz?

Comment: please look at this image [link]https://imgur.com/uAS8hoO   I want to show my data like Modified Date column but as you see in old and new value date field returns dummy string. I need somehow change it inside my function why not in html cause of this values are dynamic and I get data using anonomyous properties.

Answer (score 0):

If your AuditTrailService is using the HttpClient of Angular, then you can provide an interface for your JSON HTTP response.
Probably something like:

```
interface AuditTrailResponse {
    recordsCount: number;
    lstRecords: AuditTrailRecord[];
}
```

And in your AuditTrailService use the following notation:
`this.httpClient.get<AuditTrailResponse>('the/url/of/your/endpoint', { your: params })`

This way, `result` will be a `AuditTrailResponse` instead of `any`.

I don't fully understand the line which parses your interpolated string to JSON and AFAIK `JSON.parse()` does not produce Date objects so your `oldValue instanceof Date` check a few lines below should never be true.

But you can provide the interface:

```
interface JSChange {
    userName: string;
    timestamp: number;
    entityName: string;
    oldValue: string | Date;
    newValue: string | Date;
}
```

and if you're really sure your `z` argument complies with the interface, perform a cast to this interface.

Comment: So in my case jsonChanges just simple string in side of back end. My getAuditTrail() method returns PaginatedReponse class which is helper class for all services. lstRecords: Array<T>, totalItems: number. I just send http get request and fetch data from database. For showing data there is no problem. I just need to check if oldValue & newValue are Date and show appropriate custom format. For timstamp I use just simple date pipe in my html. But jsonchanges property is dynamic not static.More detail We have 2 tables if user changes something it automatically saving to new table which I get data